# Api-platform test Client::getResponse() is marked as @internal, what should I use instead?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a test case in Api-Platform where I am checking that when I do filtering on a collection it gets me the correct data.

Therefore if my response is:

```
{
  "hydra:member": [
       {
          "test": "123"
       },
       {
          "test": "123"
       }
  ]
}
```

I want to assert that every "test" returned is "123".

The way I am doing it is:

```php
        foreach ($client->getResponse()->toArray()['hydra:member'] as $member) {
            self::assertEquals($member['test'], "123");
        }
```

This works well but I see that the method `getResponse` is marked as `@internal` which means it should not be used outside the library. Is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Client::request()` method that returns an `ResponseInterface`, defined [here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/e8effc74ec97261545bfca145f837607e1898134/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Client.php#L87).

```
public function request(string $method, string $url, array $options = []): ResponseInterface
```

Why don't you use that response directly?